# Get the caption of optionbutton and checkbox when enabled

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get the caption of optionbutton and checkbox when value is true.

I have this code. I'm getting an error under the next.

```
    Dim c As Control, str As String
    Dim d As Control, ctr As String

    For each c in Userform1.Controls
        For each d in Userform1.Controls
            If TypeName(c) ="OptionButton" Then 
                If TypeName(d) = "CheckBox" Then
                    str = str & IIf(c = True, c.Caption & vbCrLf, "")
                    ctr = ctr & IIf(d= True, d.Caption & vbCrLf, "")
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next d
    TextBox2.Value = "PV:" & str & ctr
End sub
```

Comment: What is your goal to achieve?

Comment: Get the caption of optionbutton and checkbox when value is true

Comment: See my answer and let me know either it help you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following sub. Hope it will help you.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim c As Control, str As String, ctr As String

    For Each c In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(c) = "OptionButton" Then
            If c = True Then
                str = str & c.Caption & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If

        If TypeName(c) = "CheckBox" Then
            If c = True Then
                ctr = ctr & c.Caption & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    'TextBox2.Value = "PV:" & str & ctr
    MsgBox "PV: " & str & ctr
End Sub
```

Comment: If you found it working then please accept my answer (Tick it marked as green). It will help other visitor to understand that the question is answered.